# Program using schedule won't run when computer sleeps, or wifi goes down Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that keeps checking bitcoin price every 5 minutes and emails me when certain conditions are met using the schedule module in the PyCharm IDE, but this slows down my computer and stops when I need to restart or update anything windows.

Here's what I've got so far

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Is there any way I can have this run on an external system that doesn't lose connection to wifi and always runs?  Are there other modules that that run on interrupts/ don't slow the computer?

Comment: You should mount your program in an external service like ec2 of amazon web services, with this your program will run always

Comment: I'd second what @ÓscarContreras said - another (more approachable, imo) option might be pythonanywhere.com , but the essential solution to what you're describing is running your program on an external service.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer to your problem doesn't actually involve code.

What you might be looking to work with is something called a raspberry pi.  Its a small credit card sized computer that doesn't cost very much, I think it might cost about 30-40 bucks starting.

If you can handle the linux system, which I actually think is easier than windows and similar to Mac, you can program the raspberry pi to be a computer that's sole purpose is meant to run your program.

It won't slow down your computer because it'll be running on a different system, and as for the wifi, there's no real way to get around that unless you have multiple different service providers, unless you set the program to also monitor it's connectivity to wifi.  If you do this, there might be some sort of way that you could at least send a notification via local network to your computer, or phone depending on how comfortable you are with building local servers.

Hope that helps!